# How to dequeue messages from RabbitMQ in a scheduled time

Tags: rabbitmq, scheduled-tasks, message-queue, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ messaging service to send messages. I want to dequeue the messages that are sent on a scheduled basis and stop dequeuing the messages after 2 minutes, so that I can dequeue them on the next scheduled time.

Thanks,
R. Venkatesan

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Time-To-Live Extensions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) is what you want. Setting per-queue ttl for 2 minutes will dead-letter messages that was published more than 2 minutes ago.